# Entity Framework (5.0) entities not refreshed from database

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

After saving a record to database successfully, local data context still show the data before the change.

```
 public ActionResult Edit(Payment y)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Edit DCS LC Payments";
        DCSrecurringInvoicesEntities dcx = new DCSrecurringInvoicesEntities();
        var pvm = dcx.Payment.Where(x => x.PaymentID == y.PaymentID).First();
        pvm.ClientID = y.ClientID;
        pvm.PaymentID = y.PaymentID;

        pvm.DueDate = y.DueDate;
        pvm.MonthlyPayment = y.MonthlyPayment;
        pvm.ReceivedDate = y.ReceivedDate;
        pvm.Amount41098 = y.Amount41098;
        pvm.Paymentmethod = y.Paymentmethod;
        pvm.Penalty = y.Penalty;
        pvm.comment = y.comment;
         pvm.Discount = y.Discount;
        pvm.PaymentTerm = y.PaymentTerm;

        dcx.SaveChanges();
        // dcx.Dispose();  does not refresh data context
        // dcx.Payment.Attach(pvm); does not refresh data context
        return View("Index");
    }
```

Comment: Are you running `dcx.Payment.Attach(pvm);` first? and then calling `dcx.SaveChanges();`

Comment: no, here is the entire code:

Comment: I revised the posting, with the entire code, but format is messed up, see above

Comment: Are you sure ? Your code is correct. It should work. Anyway do this `var rowUpdated = dcx.SaveChanges();` and check if rowUpdated > 0

Comment: That should work the way it is. Are you sure `y` contains any actual changes?

Comment: Database record was revised correctly, but asp.net page still show the data before the change was made, when the page is reloaded. probably page cache is the culprit?

Comment: Try  `dcx.Payment.Attach(pvm) ;  dcx.Entry(pvm).State =EntityState.Modified; dcx.SaveChange();`

Answer (score 0):

I believe only the primary key is set on the entity that has been added once SaveChanges is called.